# Reading shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i'm using shared preferences for the settings menu of my android app.
it's working very well but i didn't know how to use these settings on my code:

For example how to use the selected language and use it in another activity:

```
    <PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="General Settings"
    android:key="general_settings"

    >
    <ListPreference 
        android:key="language"
        android:title="Language"
        android:summary="Define the default language"
        android:defaultValue="Spanish" 
        android:entries="@array/Languages"
        android:entryValues="@array/LanguagesValues"

    />
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

On code behind;

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("general_settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String lanSettings = prefs.getString("language", null);
```

Answer (score 21):

you have to set and read shared pref settings. For example:

Set:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); 
                        editor.putString("language", language);
                        editor.commit();
```

Read:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String language = settings.getString("language", "");
```

You could use a RadioGroup, set the Sharedpref and work with it.

Hope this help!

Comment: For future proofing you may want to use `editor.apply();` instead of `editor.commit();`

Comment: Using the `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)` is the correct answer. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#ReadingPrefs