# User data not cleared after Logout SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

My problem is everytime I login data stays in app even I clicked Logout and tried to login different account still getting the data of the account that I have login first ..

I did `Log.d` after logout and data is still there

This is my code

User login class

```
public class DocLogin extends Fragment {

TextView tvItemName, tvRegister;
EditText user, pass;
Button btnLogin;
String username, password;
SqlDbHelper dbhelper;
SQLController dbcon;
SharedPreferences sh_Pref;
Editor editor;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String userkey = "userKey";
public static final String passkey = "passKey";
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

public DocLogin() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc_log_in, container, false);

    dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
    dbcon.open();

    // Log in
    user = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etUser);
    pass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    // Sign up
    tvRegister = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRegDoc);
    tvRegister.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tvRegister.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocReg());
            ft.commit();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // btnLogin onClickListener
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            sharedPreferences();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successful", 20).show();

            Log.d("DocLogin", user.getText().toString());
            Log.d("LoginDetails", "username:" + user.getText());
            Log.d("LoginDetails", "password:" + pass.getText());
            Cursor cur = dbcon.getuser_information(user.getText()
                    .toString(), pass.getText().toString());
            if (cur.getCount() != 0) {

                Cursor cursor = dbcon.getDocData();
                if(cursor.getCount() !=0) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocProfile());
                    ft.commit();
                }
            } else {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity()).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Login Error");
                alertDialog
                        .setMessage("Doctor Code and Password does not match");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // dismiss dialog
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void sharedPreferences() {

    sh_Pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
            getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sh_Pref.edit();
    username = user.getText().toString();
    password = pass.getText().toString();
    editor.putString("Username", username);
    editor.putString("Password", password);
    editor.commit();
}

}
```

This is where I display user data using `TextView`

```
public class DocProfile extends Fragment {

SharedPreferences pref;
Editor editor;
SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLController dbcon;
Cursor cursor;
SqlDbHelper dbhelper;

public DocProfile() {

}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc_profile, container, false);


    dbcon = new SQLController(getActivity());
    dbcon.open();

    TextView fname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.docFirstname);
    TextView lname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.docLastname);
    TextView spec = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_spec);
    TextView loc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_location);
    TextView con = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_contact);


    String doccode = "", firstname = "", lastname = "", specialty = "", location = "", contact = "";

    Cursor c = dbcon.getDocData();
    doccode = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE));
    Log.d("DocProfile", "DocCode: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE)));
    firstname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME));
    Log.d("DocProfile", "DocCode: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME)));
    lastname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME));
    Log.d("DocProfile", "DocCode: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME)));
    specialty = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC));
    Log.d("DocProfile", "DocCode: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC)));
    location = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION));
    Log.d("DocProfile", "DocCode: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION)));
    contact = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT));
    Log.d("DocProfile", "DocCode: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT)));

    fname.setText(firstname);
    lname.setText(lastname);
    spec.setText(specialty);
    loc.setText(location);
    con.setText(contact);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logout, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.logout:

        TextView fname = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.docFirstname);
        TextView lname = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.docLastname);
        TextView spec = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.doc_spec);
        TextView loc = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.doc_location);
        TextView con = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.doc_contact);

        String vFname = fname.getText().toString();
        String vLname = lname.getText().toString();
        String vSpec = spec.getText().toString();
        String vLoc = loc.getText().toString();
        String vCon = con.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(DocLogin.MyPREFERENCES, getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        getActivity().finish();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new DocLogin());
        ft.commit();

        Log.d("Logout", "Firstname = null: " + vFname);
        Log.d("Logout", "Lastname = null: " + vLname);
        Log.d("Logout", "Specialty = null: " + vSpec);
        Log.d("Logout", "Location = null: " + vLoc);
        Log.d("Logout", "Contact = null: " + vCon);


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logout Successful", 20).show();
        return false;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

my Database handler

```
public class SQLController {

private SqlDbHelper dbhelper;
private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase database;

public SQLController(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public SQLController open() throws SQLException {
    dbhelper = new SqlDbHelper(context);
    database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    dbhelper.close();
}

public void insertData(String regid, String doc_code, String firstname,
        String lastname, String specialty, String card_id, String region,
        String location, String contact, String monday, String tuesday,
        String wednesday, String thursday, String friday, String saturday,
        String sunday, String pass, String conpass) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, regid);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE, doc_code);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, firstname);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME, lastname);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC, specialty);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CARD_ID, card_id);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_REGION, region);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION, location);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT, contact);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_MON, monday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_TUE, tuesday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_WED, wednesday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_THU, thursday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_FRI, friday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SAT, saturday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.SCHED_SUN, sunday);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONPASS, conpass);
    database.insert(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}


public Cursor getDocData() {
    String[] docData = new String[] { SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC, SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT };
    Cursor c = database.query(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, docData, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
         String getDocCode = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE));
         String getFname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME));
         String getLname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME));
         String getSpec = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC));
         String getLocation = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION));
         String getContact = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT));
    }
    return c;
}


public Cursor getuser_information(String docid, String password) {
    Cursor cursor = database.query(true, SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] { SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID,
                    SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE, SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS },
            SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE + "='"
                    + docid.toString().toLowerCase() + "' and "
                    + SqlDbHelper.COL_PASS + "='" + password + "'", null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    } else
        return cursor;

}

}
```

Comment: try in this way editor.clear().commit()

Comment: I cant find the place where you define your SharedPreferences try to define it when you write this part of code prefs.clear().commit()

Comment: its in the bottom part of Login.class

Comment: have you tried in the way of defining it above prefs.clear().commit()?

Comment: it says `Add cast to myPrefs`

Comment: I know it there ar two tipes of preferences one on android and one in java

Comment: instead of Preferences prefs; use  android.content.SharedPreferences prefs;

Comment: or use prefs declared in DocLogin (this one <sh_Pref>)

Comment: I cant understand the reason . have you tried uninstalling your app and installing it again?

Comment: yes, can you check my code where I retrieve data from sqlite .. because I put `Log.d` and the user that keeps logging in is the right value that I'm getting(sorry bad in english)

Comment: and also in `btnLogin onClick`

Comment: Why do you use  "='" instead of  "=" in getuser_information

Comment: I remove all `'` and it gives me error in `LogCat` `07-14 01:38:00.100: E/AndroidRuntime(10682): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 01:38:00.100: E/AndroidRuntime(10682): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: admin (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT reg_id, doc_code, password FROM doc_table WHERE doc_code=admin and password=admin
07-14 01:38:00.100: E/AndroidRuntime(10682):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
`

Comment: but why you need to edit you SQLite ? Your question was about clearing SharedPreferences

Comment: I just noticed after putting `Log.d` in `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(column));` that I'm getting the different data from other account not in the accoun that I am logging in

Comment: do you try it on rooted real device?

Comment: yes I am using right now

Comment: download root browser and look in your files under this  data/data/com.yourCompany.yourApp

Comment: and then ? do I need to delete some files ?

Comment: no you can view your files and see is  it empty or not

Answer (score 0):

clear method works perfectly.  Problem is that you did not update variables in your log.d.  After clear and commit you need to  read data from Shared Preferenses again.

Comment: You put some data in Shared Preferenses. After clear it try to read data from the shared preferenses. How to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573750/reading-shared-preferences

Comment: Yes. Becouse you don't have data after clear preferenses.  Try to read data  before clear - data must be existing.

Comment: After you understand it. Tell me and we fix your nullpointer exception.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand some of this new in login/logout session .. I did the link you gave and still data stays .. let me ask I should read data before `clear();` right and still data stays

Comment: Ok. Let try again. What data still exist after clear data? You save in preference only username and password.

Comment: yea .. those data that I didn't have in sharedpreference stays

Comment: What goal of the Shared Preferenses in your app? What goal of the SQLITE in your app?

Comment: goal ? sharedpreferences to hold the user data until logout .. Sqlite database of my app

Comment: Yes. Shared preferences(SP) allow to you save and read data(nothing more). in one case you save it. (preferences.put()). In another case you must read data. Before clear data from SP it is exist, after clear it does not exist. Each time before check data from SP you need read it. If you save data in varible and then clear data , Value in varible still be existing. But in SP it not exist yet. So update varible.

Comment: I mean update value of varible. I.e: int a=5; and update: a= 7;